# How to put some variables in the script into the configuration file, read and parse it from the configuration file?

Tags: database, dolphindb

For example , the connection string required by the ODBC connection is placed in the configuration file for easy maintenance.

```py
connDict = dict(`ip`port`db`uid`pwd`driver, [`192.168.xxx.xxx, `xxxxx, `xxxx, `user, "passwd", `MySQL])
odbcconn = odbc::connect("Driver={" + connDict.driver + "};Server=" + connDict.ip + ";Port=" + connDict.port + ";Database=" + connDict.db + "; Uid=" + connDict.uid + ";Pwd=" + connDict.pwd + ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following script to convert the dictionary into JSON format data conforming to the DolphinDB specification and put it in a JSON file.

```py
connDict = dict(`ip`port`db`uid`pwd`driver, [`192.168.xxx.xxx, `xxxxx, `xxxx, `user, "passwd", `MySQL])
toJson(connDict)
```

Custom functions, read JSON files and convert them into dictionaries.

```py
def getMysqlConnDictFrom Json(filePath) {
              f = file(filePath)
              arr = f.readLines()
              json = reduce(concat, trim(arr[arr != string(NULL)]))
              return fromJson(json)
}
 
connDict = getMysqlConnDictFromJson("/data/software/dolphin/server/mysqlconn.json")
```